# how to place 2 forms in one line?

Tags: html, forms

within HTML, 2 forms (each contains a button with an action which is subsequently handled by Perl code) should be placed in **one line** cause it is a back / next items implementation concerning a result set that is displayed within a table below.

should a table be used to place two forms?

Comment: No. Please don't use tables for that.

Comment: With the proper CSS rules it can be done, assuming of course the two forms are small enough for both to fit in the same link. Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Why do you even use two (??) forms, your perl code could still check what button has been clicked!!

Comment: it's an old project. yes, action was checked in prior but only the first action/button is returned when combing buttons within a form-the ui uses more than one language. the action is binded with hidden. within another site of the project, i detected that additional forms are a workaround (and time flies like an arrow). no time to rewrite much stuff and the project ends soon without being continued.

Answer (score 1):

You can place use the CSS rule `display: inline-block` to position the forms on the same line.
Here is an example:
http://dabblet.com/gist/7428241

Answer (score 0):

You may place the two forms in two separate division (`div`) elements and position them in one line using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the forms in separate divs and then float them both left to get them side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.
Example:

```
    <form style="display:inline;"></form> //Form 1
    <form style="display:inline;"></form> //Form 2
```